# P value for Normality test very small despite normal histogram

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

I've looked over the normality tests in scipy stats for both [scipy.stats.mstats.normaltest](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.normaltest.html) as well as [scipy.stats.shapiro](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.shapiro.html) and it looks like they both assume the null hypothesis is that the data they're given is normal.

Ie, a p value less than .05 would indicate that they're not normal.

I'm doing a regression with LassoCV in SKLearn, and in order to give myself better results I log transformed the answers, which gives a histogram that looks like this:

[image: Histogram of data]

Looks normal to me.

However, when I run the data through either of the two tests mentioned above I get very small p values that would indicate the data is not normal, and in a big way.

This is what I get when I use scipy.stats.shapiro

```
scipy.stats.shapiro(y)
Out[69]: (0.9919402003288269, 3.8889791653673456e-07)
```

And I get this when I run scipy.stats.mstats.normaltest:

```
scipy.stats.mstats.normaltest(y)
NormaltestResult(statistic=25.755128535282189, pvalue=2.5547293546709236e-06)
```

It seems implausible to me that my data would test out as being so far from normality with the histogram it has.

Is there something causing this discrepancy, or am I not interpreting the results correctly?

Comment: Do you have a large number of data points? Even if the distribution 'looks normal', if there are many observations then subtle differences between the distribution and a normal distribution will be picked up. Try log-scaling the y-axis of your histogram, it could be that the distribution is well matched by a normal close to the peak but not in the wings.

Comment: [P-P plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93P_plot) are often helpful for visualizing how your sample deviates from some theoretical distribution. You can use [`scipy.stats.probplot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.probplot.html) to produce one.

Comment: *"Looks normal to me."*  It looks like it has positive skew to me. :)  Judging the normality of a distribution by eye is probably not very reliable. @AngusWilliams' comment is important: how many data points do you have?

Comment: In such a case you could use skewness and curtosis instead of a normality test. See for instance here in the "statistical analyses" section: http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fpsyg.2015.00653/full

Comment: @AngusWilliams - 1460 data points.  I actually log transformed the data to make it more 'normal' to use for regression.

Comment: @ali_m Thank you, will look at it.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser - I think what I'm trying to determine is whether or not it fits a normal distribution for something with N(sampleAverage, sampleSTD) rather than something that's standardized normal.  Perhaps what I need is a chi-square test with the hypothesized distribution characteristics as the null hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers on the vertical axis are the number of observations for the respective class, then the sample size is about 1500. For such a large sample size goodness-of-fit tests are rarely useful. But is it really necessary that your data is perfectly normally distributed? If you want to analyze the data with a statistical method, is this method maybe robust under ("small") deviations from the normal distribution assumption? 
In practice the question is usually "Is the normal distribution assumption acceptable" for my statistical analysis. A perfect normal distribution is very rarly available. 
An additional comment on histograms: One has to be careful by interpreting data from histograms because if the data "looks normal" or not may depend on the width of the histogram classes. Histograms are only hints which should be treated with caution.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this n times and take the mean of the p values, you will get what you expect. Run it in a loop in a Monte Carlo way.